# В чем отличие между записью "T extends Comparable<T>" и "? T extends Comparable<T>"?

Tags: java, generics

В чем отличие между `T extends Comparable<T>` и `? T extends Comparable<T>`? И где какая запись применяется?

Comment: Ответ уже был дан, но если хотите узнать больше вы можете почитать учебную документацию java [С русским переводом](https://docs-oracle-com.translate.goog/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### `T extends Comparable<T>`

Описывает переменную типа, ограниченную сверху при помощи `extends`, то есть,
некий обобщённый класс `T` должен реализовать интерфейс `Comparable<T>`, т.е. объекты такого класса поддерживают естественный порядок и их можно сравнивать и упорядочивать при помощи метода `int compareTo(T that)`.

Может использоваться для обычных обобщённых классов

```java
public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T field;
    //геттер/сеттер/конструктор
}
```

т.е. класс `Foo` может создаваться не для любых классов `T`, а только реализующих `Comparable` типа `Integer`, `String`, `LocalDate`, и т.п.:

```java
Foo<Integer> fooInt = new Foo<>(123); // ok
Foo<Random> fooRand = new Foo<>(new Random()); // ошибка, Random не является Comparable
// Type parameter 'java.util.Random' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<java.util.Random>'
```

Соответственно, массивы/списки/стримы таких объектов можно сортировать, для них можно искать минимум/максимум и т.д.:

- [`Collections :: public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)

Доп.информация:

- [Oracle Tutorial: Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

---

##### `? extends Comparable`

Такая запись называется wildcard или подстановкой с верхней границей ([upper-bounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)).

С её помощью можно организовать *ковариантность*, т.е. `List<Integer>` является подтипом `List<Comparable>`. `List<? extends Comparable>` может содержать объекты, которые являются `Comparable` или наследуются от `Comparable`.

Это можно применять для того, чтобы коллекции классов, реализующих `Comparable`, присвоить коллекцию объектов с конкретными реализациями:

```java
List<Integer>   ints = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3);
List<String>    strs = Arrays.asList("111", "xxxx", "aaaa");
List<LocalDate> dats = Arrays.asList(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 1), LocalDate.of(2025, 5, 12));
List<? extends Comparable> comps = ints;
comps = strs;
comps = dats;
```

или же передать такую коллекцию в некий метод, например, для сортировки:

```java
public static void sortAndPrint(List<? extends Comparable> list) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("sorted: " + list);
}
sortAndPrint(ints); // sorted: [2, 3, 4]
sortAndPrint(strs); // sorted: [111, aaaa, xxxx]
sortAndPrint(dats); // sorted: [2020-11-01, 2023-02-20, 2025-05-12]
```

---

##### `? super Comparable`

Такая запись называется подстановкой с нижней границей ([lower-bounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)).

С её помощью можно организовать *контравариантность*, т.е. `List<Comparable>` является подтипом `List<? super Integer>`.

Также можно использовать для присваивания или передачи в функции:

```java
List<Comparable> comps2 = Arrays.asList(269, 123, 351);
List<? super Integer> ints2 = comps2;
// Collections.sort(ints2); // Ошибка! 
// reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that capture of ? super Integer conforms to Comparable<? super T>
Collections.sort(comps2);
System.out.println(ints2); // [123, 269, 351]
```

Коллекция с типом `? super T` может использоваться только в качестве *приёмника* данных, например, для копирования списков существует метод:
[`Collections::public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy-java.util.List-java.util.List-) :

```java
Collections.copy(ints2, ints);
System.out.println(comps2); // [2, 3, 4]
System.out.println(ints2); // [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Кстати, а в методе `copy()` в качестве типа первого параметра `dest` разве обязательно указывать именно `List<? super T>`? Ведь можно было бы указать просто  `List<T>`, тогда при передаче первым параметром какой-нибудь коллекции тип данных распознался бы, а второй параметр метода совершенно верно требует `? extends T`, то есть, либо тип `T`, либо его подкласс, поэтому "приёмник" данных в любом случае будет содержать суперкласс (или же данный класс).